# If $|G|=3^3 13$ then $G$ has a non-trivial normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If $|G|=3^3 13$ prove that $G$ has a non-trivial normal subgroup

---

since $13$ is prime that divides $|G|$ from Cauchy's theorem we get that it exist a subgroup with order $13$, because the order is prime the group is cyclic and Abelian, thus it's a normal subgroup.

The solution for this exercise was using the Sylow theorems to prove this, which is way more time-consuming, is my answer wrong ?

Comment: Just because a subgroup is abelian doesn't mean that it is normal, I'm afraid.

Comment: @LewisMacRae it's true I can't commute $ghg^{-1} $ since $g\in G$ not in my Abelian subgroup

Comment: @LewisMacRae is my answer correct ? I am trying not to use exactly the solution of the exercise

Comment: Avoid Sylow?  It follows from Feit-Thompson :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is incorrect. For example in $S_{3}$ . The subgroup $\{(1),(12)\}$ is abelian as it is of order $2$ but it is NOT normal in $S_{3}$.

The correct solution is :-

Let $n_{13}$ denote the number of Sylow-13 Subgroups .

Then from Sylow's third theorem .

$n_{13} = 13k+1$ for some non-negative integer $k$.

And $n_{13}| 27$.

So $k=0$ or $1$.

If $n_{13}=1$ . Then by again by uniqueness of the subgroup you have that it is normal(By sylow's theorem the sylow subgroups of a particular order are conjugates) and hence it will prove our claim.

If $n_{13}=27$ and $n_{3}=1$ . Then again the unique subgroup of order $27$ is normal and it would prove the claim.

The only case that requires special treatment is $n_{13}=27$ and $n_{3}=13$. But this is simply not possible. As You get $12\cdot 27=324$ elements of order $13$.

And you are left with atmost $27$ more elements. But you cannot fit them inside $13$ subgroups of order $27$. Hence you must have only $1$ subgroup of order $27$. Which would be normal by uniqueness .

Hence proved.

Answer (score 0):

I want to show that the number of $Syl_{13}(G)=1$

From the $1st$ theorem, it exists such subgroup.

From the $3nd$ theorem $n_{13}=\{1,27\}$

If $n_{13}=1$ we're done.

If  $n_{13}=27$ then there are $27$ subgroups of order $13$ that means $27\times 12+1=325$ elements.

$G$ also have groups with orders $3,9,27$ that cannot be contained in the above subgroups since are relative primes. Then we will have $2+8+26+1$ additional elements, which make a total of $362> |G|$

Comment: This is not true. if you take the union of the $27$ subgroups of order $13$ then you get $12\cdot 27$ elements and not $27\cdot 13$. Because identity is common to them all

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I missed that, but I think my idea is still holding, $12\cdot 27 =324$ but $G$ also have subgroups of order $3, 9, 27$ so $324+3+9+27>351$

Comment: Yeah correct. You should edit that in your answer

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: I have posted a answer in case you are interested . You edit that part in and I'll upvote it

Comment: Also you have to take into account that you are again overcounting the identity. When you are adding 3+9+27 all of them have identity in common. You cannot add like that

Comment: And in any case those subgroups of order $3,9$ are contained inside some sylow subgroup of order $27$ . So you cannot take disjoint union

Comment: I'd much rather argue that if I have more than two subgroups of order 27 then I'll have a problem as after taking those 324 elements of order 13 ( note that any two 13 order subgroups cannot have elements in common other than identity. Because then they would generate the same subgroup.). I have only 27 elements left , one of which is identity. So I can have atmost 1 subgroup of order $27$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron i edit my answer and corrected my solution, I hope it's good.